# Java Riak "Channel closed while operation in progress" error

Tags: java, key-value, riak

I'm trying to execute TasteOfRiak.java from basic tutorial (https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.0.0/developing/getting-started/java/ ) but Riak logs error during execution:

```
602441 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] ERROR com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - Channel closed while operation in progress; id:-1014012123 127.0.0.1:8098
```

Below code:

```
private static RiakCluster setUpCluster() throws UnknownHostException {
    RiakNode node = new RiakNode.Builder()
            .withRemoteAddress("127.0.0.1")
            .withRemotePort(8098)
            .build();

    RiakCluster cluster = new RiakCluster.Builder(node)
            .build();
    cluster.start();

    return cluster;
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    try {
        RiakObject quoteObject = new RiakObject()
                .setContentType("text/plain")
                .setValue(BinaryValue.create("You're dangerous, Maverick"));
        System.out.println("Basic object created");

        Namespace quotesBucket = new Namespace("quotes");

        Location quoteObjectLocation = new Location(quotesBucket, "Iceman");
        System.out.println("Location object created for quote object");

        StoreValue storeOp = new StoreValue.Builder(quoteObject)
                .withLocation(quoteObjectLocation)
                .build();
        System.out.println("StoreValue operation created");

        RiakCluster cluster = setUpCluster();
        RiakClient client = new RiakClient(cluster);
        System.out.println("Client object successfully created");

        StoreValue.Response storeOpResp = client.execute(storeOp);
        System.out.println("Object storage operation successfully completed");
```

'Client object successfully created' is the last printed message before error. Do you know the way to fix it?

Comment: You're using the wrong port. See my answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638810/java-riak-connection-problems/47646869#47646869